# How to enable actuator health for kibana and apm-server

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, kibana, spring-boot-actuator, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
management.health.elasticsearch.enabled=true
```

How to enable actuator health for kibana and apm-server, the above configuration doesn't provide health information other than elasticsearch server

Answer (score 0):

There is no auto-configured Kibana and APM Server health check from Spring Boot as of the latest version (Spring Boot Actuator reference: [2.8.1. Auto-configured HealthIndicators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-health-indicators)). As you said, you can find `elasticsearch` using [`ElasticsearchRestHealthIndicator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.4.5/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchRestHealthIndicator.java).

You need to write a custom health indicator that is not complicated. Start here: [2.8.2. Writing Custom HealthIndicators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#writing-custom-healthindicators).

All you need to know the correct endpoints to detect the health of the wanted servers.

**Kibana**

Kibana exposes REST GET endpoint about the status which can be called by Spring to determine its health:

- `GET localhost:5601/status` returns status for a node
- `GET localhost:5601/api/status` returns more detailed status information

*Note: You might want to validate these endpoints as I haven't found any official source.*

**APM Server**

APM server provides only one endpoint on the root path ([source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/server/current/server-info.html)):

- `GET localhost:8200`